# How to extract data from an RSS feed using Perl with XML::Feed

Tags: xml, perl, rss

I am trying to grab a piece of information about the length of a MP3 file from an RSS feed.

Here is the Perl script I am hacking away at:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::Feed;
use Data::Dumper;

my $rssurl      = "http://librivox.org/rss/4273";
my $feed = XML::Feed->parse(URI->new($rssurl))
    or die XML::Feed->errstr;
print $feed->title, "\n";
print $feed->description, "\n";
for my $entry ($feed->entries) {
#       print "entery is [$entry]\n";
#       print Dumper( $entry );
        print $entry->title, "\n";
        print $entry->{'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'}{'duration'} . "\n";
        print $entry->duration . "\n";
}
```

When I run the script I get this output:

```
Conquest Over Time by SHAARA, Michael
<p>Pat Travis, a spacer renowned for his luck, is suddenly quite out of it. His job is to beat his competitors to sign newly-Contacted human races to commercial contracts...

But what can he do when he finds he's on a planet that consults astrology for literally every major decision - and he has arrived on one of the worst-aspected days in history?

Michael Shaara, later to write the Pulitzer-winning novel "The Killer Angels", wrote this story for Fantastic Universe in 1956. (Summary by Mark F. Smith)</p>
1 - Section 1

Can't locate object method "duration" via package "XML::Feed::Entry::Format::RSS" at ./get_feed.pl line 15.
```

If I add `print Dumper( $entry );` for debugging I can see this bit of data:

```
$VAR1 = bless({
  _version => "2.0",
  entry => {
    "enclosure" => {
      length => "9.6MB",
      type => "audio/mpeg",
      url => "http://www.archive.org/download/conquest_over_time_1005_librivox/conquestovertime_1_shaara_64kb.mp3",
    },
    "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" => { block => "No", duration => "00:20:00", explicit => "No" },
    "item" => ("\n    " x 12),
    "link" => "http://www.archive.org/download/conquest_over_time_1005_librivox/conquestovertime_1_shaara_64kb.mp3",
    "title" => "1 - Section 1",
  },
}, "XML::Feed::Entry::Format::RSS")
```

The piece of data I want is the duration `00:20:00`. How do I get that in my script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks there's a primary key called `entry` that you need to use:

```
$entry->{'entry'}{'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd'}{'duration'}
```

Comment: awesome! that did it.

Answer (score 1):

You would be unwise to extract information from the internals of an object like this. The only guaranteed functionality is that described in the documentation, and the author is free to change the implementation at any time as along as that interface is unchanged.

In particular this is an unusual implementation of XML *namespaces*: the element you want is labelled `itunes:duration` in the XML, and the namespace is `itunes`. This is to distinguish it from any other `duration` element that may appear in the document. You should extract the data you want using XPath as described in your previous question. This brief program does what you need without using `XML::Feed`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple 'get';
use XML::XPath;

my $rssurl = 'http://librivox.org/rss/4273';
my $xml    = get $rssurl;
my $xp     = XML::XPath->new(xml => $xml);

my ($channel) = $xp->findnodes('/rss/channel');
printf "Channel Title:       %s\n\n", $channel->find('title');
printf "Channel Description: %s\n\n", $channel->find('description');

print "ITEMS\n";
for my $item ($xp->findnodes('/rss/channel/item')) {
  printf "  Item Title:    %s\n", $item->find('title');
  printf "  Item Duration: %s\n", $item->find('itunes:duration');
  print "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Channel Title:       Conquest Over Time by SHAARA, Michael

Channel Description: <p>Pat Travis, a spacer renowned for his luck, is suddenly quite out of it. His job is to beat his competitors to sign newly-Contacted human races to commercial contracts...

But what can he do when he finds he's on a planet that consults astrology for literally every major decision - and he has arrived on one of the worst-aspected days in history?

Michael Shaara, later to write the Pulitzer-winning novel "The Killer Angels", wrote this story for Fantastic Universe in 1956. (Summary by Mark F. Smith)</p>

ITEMS
  Item Title:    1 - Section 1
  Item Duration: 00:20:00

  Item Title:    2 - Section 2
  Item Duration: 00:18:35

  Item Title:    3 - Section 3
  Item Duration: 00:25:12

  Item Title:    4 - Section 4
  Item Duration: 00:16:38
```